# how to control/save images took with android camera programmatically?

Tags: android, save, android-camera, file-rename, image-capture

i've been trying to create a camera-related app. i know that i could create it programmatically from top, but i would prefer using the one that the phone supports.

what i mean is, rather then creating the camera from 0, i would/could call the camera activity. after all, it provides all the system and gui that i needed.

however, the problem is i wanted the result/image took to be saved in a folder that i created before, rather then saving it in the default camera folder. and also renaming the image took that instant from the default 'image' to names that i preferred.

how do i control that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Here am saving picture to `sdcard` and also changing its name while saving.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

Uri mUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                "pic"+ String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg"));

intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mUri);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the Camera applicaton source code, it allows for startActivityForResult(..) that can return the image back to you. This is ideally what you'd like to do.

As a Little hint:

[MediaStore](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)

Answer (score 0):

Use below method to take picture, SD_CARD_TEMP_DIR is the path and the image name you want it to store.   Hope it help

```
     private void   takePicture(){

    SD_CARD_TEMP_DIR = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "farmerImage"+CassavaPref.getInstance(this).getImageSuffix()+".jpg";
    file =new File(SD_CARD_TEMP_DIR);
    Intent takePictureFromCameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    takePictureFromCameraIntent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
    startActivityForResult(takePictureFromCameraIntent, 1111);
}
```

Comment: 01-22 17:56:04.470: E/AndroidRuntime(4924): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

01-22 17:56:04.470: E/AndroidRuntime(4924): java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: first. add permision " write external storage" in your manifest, and give in which line you are getting expception