# Android name image programmatically

Tags: android, camera

I want to give a custom name to the image captured through the camera programmatically. I have used the snippets of codes given here [how to control/save images took with android camera programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891964/how-to-control-save-images-took-with-android-camera-programmatically/) but it still doesn't work and the image is stored with the default name. Why?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button cameraButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.takepicture);

        cameraButton.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener(){ 
            public void onClick(View v ){
                //Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
                //startActivityForResult(intent,0);
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                Uri mUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                                "pic_"+ String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg"));

                intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mUri);
                startActivityForResult(intent,0);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16374701/capture-image-with-camera-in-android-and-save-with-a-custom-name

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: @Priya please see my updates post, I have added the code too.

Comment: @Lokesh I couldn't make it work. Could you please write tell me where exactly to put this code?

Comment: @user2387107: have you tried Hamid Shatu solution..??

Comment: @Lokesh Yes I did. I look for the taken picture in the "Album" of my Sony Xperia Miro, I do see the picture but with the default name. Is this the right location?

Comment: @user2387107: I posted answer>..try with my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try as follows...

```
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    String fullPath = "";
    File imageFile = null;
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String pictureName = "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg";

    fullPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/ImageFolder/" + pictureName;

    File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/ImageFolder/");
    dir.mkdirs();

    imageFile = new File(fullPath);
    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(imageFile));
    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
public void CapturePhoto() 
    {
        try
        {
            myFilesDir = new File( getFilesDir()+"/MyDir");
         if(! mfilesDir.exists() )
            myFilesDir.mkdirs();

        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,Uri.fromFile(new File(myFilesDir.toString()+"/temp.jpeg")));

        startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_CALLBACK);
    }
    catch ( ActivityNotFoundException e )
    {
        Log.e( TAG, "No camera: " + e );
    }
    catch ( Exception e )
    {
        Log.e( TAG, "Cannot make photo: " + e );
    }
}`
```

Comment: did you check manually in sd card, whether it creates file or not?

Comment: I look for the taken picture in the "Album" of my Sony Xperia Miro, I do see the picture but with the default name. Is this the correct way of looking for that taken picture? Is that the right location?

Comment: go to external storage (sd-card) and look for directory "MyDir".

Comment: I am very sorry Umer, I am using someone else's cell phone and I just saw this message that "Insert an SD card for mounting". Is there any other way I can test the code you provided without the SD card? with Internal memory

Comment: I have update the code. Check this if it work for you.

Comment: Thank You Umer but I guess I'd have to test it with the SD card, because the name is still the default name. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Here I saved image with current date and time as name:

```
public class CameraActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 0;
    static Uri capturedImageUri=null;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_junit_test);
        Button cameraButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cameraButton);

        cameraButton.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener(){ 
            private int CAMERA_RESULT;

            public void onClick(View v ){
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),  (cal.getTimeInMillis()+".jpg"));
                if(!file.exists()){
                    try {
                        file.createNewFile();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }else{
                    file.delete();
                    try {
                        file.createNewFile();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                capturedImageUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                Intent i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, capturedImageUri);
                startActivityForResult(i, CAMERA_RESULT);
            }
        });
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {  
            //Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            //imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap( getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),  capturedImageUri);
                //imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Image Saved As"+bitmap, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You very much Lokesh for providing this code. I am very sorry I am using someone else's cell phone and I just saw this message that "Insert an SD card for mounting". Is there any other way I can test the code you provided without the SD card? with Internal memory

Comment: Have you added  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> permission in manifest file??

Comment: Yes I have but I think I'd have to try the code with the SD card, as it isn't working without it.